# How to loop through folders and apply function on files in these folders

Tags: r, function, loops

I have multiple similarly named but different folders, each containing similarly named but different csv files.

For example, I have three folders named "output", each containing "image.csv" and "cells.csv".

How do I loop through each "output" folder, then read each csv files in the folder and apply function onto these files?
Here's what I tried :

Firstly, I list the folders named "output":

```
dirs<-list.dirs()
dirs<-dirs[grepl("output",dirs)]
```

Then I want to set up a function to join both csv files, something like below (codes are incomplete though, please help to correct this):

```
object_extraction<-function(x){ image<-read.csv(image.csv, header=T, sep=",") 
                                cells<-read.csv(cells.csv, header=T, sep=",")
                                object<-dplyr::inner_join(cells,image,by="ImageNumber")
                                return(object)}
```

Finally I want to loop the function above through the "output" folders

```
object<-list() 
for(i in 1:length(dirs)){
object[[i]]<-object_extraction(dirs[i])
```

Thank you

Comment: Whats the error message you got?

Comment: Error in file(file,"rt"):cannot open the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the path to read csv dynamic in your function

```
object_extraction<-function(x){ 
  image<-read.csv(paste0(x, '/image.csv'), header=T, sep=",") 
  #header = T and sep = ',' is default in read.csv so this should 
  #work without specifying them as well.
  cells<-read.csv(paste0(x, '/cells.csv'))
  object<-dplyr::inner_join(cells,image,by="ImageNumber")
  return(object)
}
```

and then apply the function to each folder.

```
dirs <- list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)
dirs <- grep('output', dirs, value = TRUE)
result <- lapply(dirs, object_extraction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two errors I can spot in your code:

You need to use the directory name form the `dirs` variable, eg:

```
object_extraction<-function(x){ 
  image<-read.csv(file.path(x, "image.csv"), header=T, sep=",") 
  cells<-read.csv(file.path(x, "cells.csv"), header=T, sep=",")
  object<-dplyr::inner_join(cells,image,by="ImageNumber")
  return(object)
}
```

And the file names should be strings, `"image.csv"` and `"cells.csv"`

HTH